How to correctly display the range values from rc-slider
I am trying to use the rc-slider component, however, I am having some challenges since the documentation is kind of outdated. I would like to understand how I can accomplish two things.

I would like to use range, however, as you can see from my code, it seems the values are being concatenated instead of displaying the correct values.
How can I make the tooltip to only be displayed when I drag or hover over the ranges? As you can see from the below sandbox, the tooltips are always being displayed.

This is the codesandbox.
Basically I am trying to achieve the "Range with custom tooltip" behavior from this example: https://react-component.github.io/slider/?path=/story/rc-slider--handle
Thanks in advance.
